How to Open Apps on the Active Monitor in a Dual Display Setup with MacBook?
I’m using a MacBook with a dual monitor setup. Whenever I activate the dock on my second screen (where the spotlight also appears), any applications I open default to the MacBook’s primary screen rather than the secondary monitor where I’m working.
Is there a method to ensure that applications open on the monitor that’s currently active, possibly determined by the location of the mouse or the activation of the dock?
